# How to upload RPM build info from Jenkins to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, conan

We are building RPM installers using Jenkins and uploading them to an RPM repo on a self hosted Artifactory server (Commercial Licensed).

I want to also upload the build information for the RPM as well as the conan info about the RPM.

*PS: The application is written in C++ and managed using conan (conanfile.py) and then CPack is used to create the RPM.*

We upload the RPM to an Artifactory RPM Repo using curl + XPUT.

Our pipeline is basically as follow:

```
// Stage: Build
client     = Artifactory.server().newConanClient()
build_info = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
client.run("install ..", build_info )
client.run("build ..", build_info )
// Stage: Test
ctest
// Stage: package
cmake --build . --target package
// Stage: Upload
curl -H "key" -XPUT "https://our.artifactory/artifactory/repo_rpm/path/tp/package.rpm" -T "pacakge.rpm"
```

So from the above we have the conan build_info (and lockfile) as well as the actual pipeline that we want to associate with package.rpm when uploaded.

What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: Generation of BuildInfo in Conan 1.X had some limitations. Conan 2.0 has improved over this issue creating new custom commands in https://github.com/conan-io/conan-extensions/tree/main/extensions/commands/art, I'd recommend trying to update and use the new commands.